# Is it possible to upload files and images which are not jpg, png, etc. in the questions?

Tags: support

I wonder if it is possible to include files and images which are not the allowed ones, e.g. .eps, in the questions.

If on one side this rises the problem of uploading potencially malicious files, on the other I think that this could be useful for a better explanation and description of the questions, as in the case one needs to provide complex functions or data.

Comment: I guess that SE will not change its policy very quickly or even just for one site... seems like we are stuck with what is allowed. Do you have anything more specific in mind? Otherwise the discussion will be too generic.

Comment: It happened to me that I created an eps figures with tikz for a journal, but I had issues since the editor was not able to open it (see "Corrupted eps figures" on tex.stackexchange.com). In fact, I try to open it with Photoshop and I got and error. My installation should be fine, but I doubt it is a bug of tikz. So I put the code in the question and other guys from the community checked that the figures where produced correctly with tikz, although they do not open in Photoshop.

Comment: Now I have 2 different outputs from different MMA versions, and I' d like to ask a question about that, but since the outputs are long and it takes time to produce them it would be easier to upload the results in order to compare them.

Comment: Right now the only way then is to provide download links for your files (happens quite a bit on this site, e.g. for image or other data).

Comment: Most (all?) web browsers can't display PostScript anyway, so trying to include these as images seems doomed to failure. The best way is probably to use an upload site like [ge.tt](http://ge.tt/), which I've used many times successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to note is that while the image uploader to stack.imgur only works with certain formats, the image inclusion format

```
 ![description][1]
 [1]: http://image.url
```

does work with images hosted in other sites. I have not tested whether it will work with an external EPS figure, but in general this will be browser-dependent as not all browsers can display those files anyway.

Thus, if you don't want to convert your file to jpg or png, then your best bet is to use a file hosting site and provide a link. You can also do both: provide the converted image so people get an idea of what is in there, and a link to the EPS file if it's important for some reason.